# Xamarin Forms (IOS, Droid)- PanGestureRecognizer for whole form

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipe, gesture

I am writing a cross-platform application (IOS, Droid) and like to catch all the Pan Gestures.

The problem is that I have (buttons + Webview) on my interface. none of them catch the "Pan Gestures". If the user swipe over the button I catch only the click event.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" />
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

<Button text="Test" />
<Webview />

</Grid>

void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
//My code here
}
```

It should detect the Pan event anywhere, but it did not do with the Webview and button.

Idea

Can I put a transparent control over the form that can allow click events to go through, but at the same time can catch the Pan event only?

I tried to use custom render and nothing help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean, can I add a full screen mask that catch swipe events only, and allow click to go for the behind controlls?

Comment: No, once you put the view over the top, it will negate all gestures on the views underneath.

Comment: Then, how to get the required result? Is there no idea, please?  How to make a full form listener for the pan gestures only whatever the child controls are?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t have the answer. The other issue I see is that webviews typically have their own set of gestures based on the content they contain, i.e. JavaScript, natural scrolling, etc. So yeah, it sounds tricky but I’m sure someone out there has the proper answer.

Comment: Thanks Brad Dixon. I already started to make a tricky solution. I listen to the webpage event, and then pass the swipe even to my app using javascript. This will work with the Webview, but not with the Buttons. Thanks anyway

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!